# Absolute full heigth and bottom margin

Tags: css

I'm currently working on my layout.

I have two left columns, not begining from the top of the document.

html:

```
<div id="site-logo">logo</div>
<section id="left-column">
    <nav>nav</nav>
</section>
<header>header</header>
<main id="main-section">
    <section id="second-left-column">
        <nav id="sub-nav">sub nav</nav>
    </section>
    <section id="content">content</section>
</main>
```

css:

```
body { position: relative; }

header { 
    background-color:red;
    height: 50px;
}
#left-column {
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    background-color:black;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    top:100px;    
    bottom: 0px;
}
#site-logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:yellow;
  position: absolute;

}
#second-left-column{
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color:grey;
  top: 25px;
}
#main-section {
  margin-left: 150px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
#content {
  margin-left:150px;
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 800px;
}
```

[There is the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jm4j9h04/3/)

I would like to have both the columns ending at the end of the document, hoefully at the same line than the content (blue)

How can I avoid the different margin bottom?

I can put the logo (yellow) inside the column if needed. We **must keep** the white strange space inside the layout

Comment: why aren't you using floats? your choice or some other reason? The result is kind of a mess. I could try to provide an alternative but I'm not sure exactly what you want it to look like

Comment: I need the columns to have 100% of heigth possible, I thought it was impossible with float property

Comment: you can do float and give it `height: 100%`

Comment: strange... height 100% isn't working even without float on jsfiddle..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add a wrap div for all your divs and set it as `overflow:hidden`, see https://jsfiddle.net/jm4j9h04/4/

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;">        
<div id="site-logo">logo</div>
        <section id="left-column">
            <nav>
                nav
            </nav>
        </section>
        <header>
            header
        </header>
        <section id="main-section">

            <section id="second-left-column">
                <nav id="sub-nav">
                    sub nav
                </nav>
            </section>
            <section id="content">
                content
            </section>

        </section>
</div>

body {   position: relative;}

header { 
    background-color:red;
    height: 50px;
}
#left-column {
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    background-color:black;
    top:100px;    
    bottom: 0px;
}
#site-logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:yellow;
  position: absolute;

}
#second-left-column{
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color:grey;
  top: 65px;
}
#main-section {
  margin-left: 150px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
#content {

  margin-left:150px;

  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 800px;

}
```